# How to multiplay an array of Integers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

I have two arrays of integers and I want to multiply them together like the following:

```
int[] arr1 = {6, 1}; // This represents the number 16

int[] arr2 = {4, 2}; // This represents the number 24
```

I want to store them in a new array so that the product appears as:

```
int[] productArray = {4, 8, 3};
```

I get how to do it with multiplying numbers like 2 x 24 since I can just push those into values into the product array. But when it comes to expanding beyond a single digit I am lost.

Comment: how do you want to perform the multiplication, with java standard, or with unlimited number of digits? (like for creating huge prime number based encrytion keys)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to do this? Regardless, here is an example:

```
int total1; // to find what the array represents in #
for (int c = 0; c < arr1.length() - 1; c++) {
 total1 += arr1[c] * Math.pow(10, (c+1)); // takes the number and adds it to the decimal number it should be
}
int total2;
for (int c = 0; c < arr2.length() - 1; c++) {
 total1 += arr2[c] * Math.pow(10, (c+1));
}
String s = Integer.toString(total2*total1);
for (int c = s.length()-1; c >= 0; c--) { // adds int to array backwards
  productArray.add(Integer.parseInt(s.atIndex(c)));
}
```

Notes: I have not bug tested this or run it through the JVM. Java isn't my usual programming language so I may have made a few mistakes. the "productArray" needs to be an ArrayList<> instead. I suspect that Integer.parseInt() is only for strings, so you may have to search for the char version of the function. Also, you need include Math...

Comment: this is wrong, he wants to simulate Multiplication as humans learns in school, your code does not multiply 16 * 24

Comment: @AlexWien I realized I made a mistake a bit ago and edited the code, so I'm not sure which "version" of it ur referring too, is this one wrong as well? Is her really emulating school? Since when did we write numbers backwards?

Comment: @MikeG: It's perfectly reasonable to store numbers from right to left so you can loop from beginning to end when doing multiplication or addition.  Also, "emulating school" is an excellent way to learn about arbitrary precision math libraries.  I don't know why you're being so hard on the OP.

Comment: @mellamokb I didn't mean to be hard on the OP, so I apologies. I was confused as to how AlexWien came to the conclusion that the OP was emulating school, b/c I hadn't noticed anything that looked as though it was trying to emulate school. When I said "we" I meant schools.

Comment: since when we write backwards: since after the romans, the arabic digits were introduced, but only for the arabics (that read from right to left) they are well suited. since then our numbers are not ideal, try to read a number with 12 digits. you cannot read it whitout jumping and scanning forward and backward.

Comment: @mellamokb BigInteger and encryption modules that have to multiply digits with thousands digits use that, and that works like we haved learned in school, not with binary arithmetics!

Comment: @AlexWien I'm mildly impressed at either your research or your natural knowledge.

Comment: @MikeG i read that arabic digits..., when i was searching on wiki for BigEndian vs LittleEndian, thats exactly the same Problem

Answer (score 3):

```
int arr1num, arr2num, product;
multiplier = 1;
for (i = arr1.size();i>0;i--){
arr1num = arr1num + (arr1[i] * multiplier);
multiplier = multiplier * 10;
}
```

--do this also for the second array

-- now we have arr1num and arr2num as the numbers of both arrays and
just get the product

```
product = arr1num * arr2num;
```

-- now store it in an array

```
int divisor = 10;
int number;
for(i=0;i<int.length();i++){

number = product % divisor;
productArray.add(number);
divisor = divisor * 10;
}
```

Comment: you can use `a *= b` rather than `a = a* b`, this makes things a little neater.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this (although it's not the best algorithm you could use to do this):

```
public static int[] multiplyArrays(int[] a, int[] b){
    //turns arrays into integers
    String num1 = "";
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
        num1 += a[i];
    }

    String num2 = "";
    for (int i = b.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
        num2 += b[i];
    }

    //does calculation
    char[] answer = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1) * Integer.parseInt(num2)).toCharArray();

    //converts char array into int array
    int[] answer2 = new int[answer.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
        answer2[answer.length - i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer[i]));
    }

    return answer2;
}
```

Comment: Why are your for loops adding? 6+1 doesn't equal 16.... sorry, I'm just a little confused.

Comment: Never mind, I just realized you were using a String, not a number.